# Complex sql statement for showing the table names

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a database with tables named Mark, Mask, Matk, Mauk
Each tables have some columns and a column named date where the current date is stored in the php's date("h:i:sa d/m/Y") format.

Now I want to select the **table** names whose last column's date is less than 5 mins away from now.
I hope you understand my above statement.

I know I would have to do this for the last part: TIMESTAMP(NOW())-TIMESTAMP(Last columns date) < 300.
However I couldn't do the other parts.
P.S I am using the database in a C# app.

**EDIT**:I'm guessing the code should be something like this:`SHOW TABLES FROM db WHERE NOW()-SELECT`date`FROM TABLES ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 <= 300`

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using.  I would guess MySQL.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

How about leaving out the `timestamp` part?

```
where LastColumnDate >= now() - interval 5 minute
```

I am assuming you are using MySQL based on your sample code.

Comment: Doesn't now() return a timestamp?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman . . . `now()` returns *something*.  When used in a context where a `datetime` is expected, the *something* is correctly interpreted as a `datetime`.  Otherwise, it might be a string or integer.  But, in this context, it gets correctly treated as/converted to a `datetime`.