# Looping a MYSql database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

My database have tables names `Ai,En,Ma`
Each table have 2 columns and a column named `date`. 
I want to get the table names whose date of the last column is no more than 5 mins from now.
I am not very good with C# So I will write this in pseudo-code and some C#.Can someone convert this to C#?

```
`sql_connect("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=")
 tables = sql_command("SHOW TABLES IN db")
 table_name = []
 for x in tables:
      table_name.append(x)
 now = date.now()
 result = []
 for i in table_names:
      cmd = sql_command("SELECT `date` from {0} WHERE TIMESTAMP(now)-TIMESTAMP(`last date`)<=300")
      if cdm returns something:
         result.append(cmd)
 for a in result:
      listbox.add(a)
```

Comment: It is not the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834456/complex-sql-statement-for-showing-the-table-names ?

Comment: Yes. I realized that this cannot be done with sql alone. I need some loops as well.

Comment: But you are not asking a question, you want the whole code to be written to you. I doubt that someone will do this for you as this is a little bit too much.

Comment: I see, I think sql is not good for my purpose anyway, I will switch to a text file for storing the data. Thanks.